# Запрос у mysql, для построения массива, для древовидной структуры

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую

Представим такую структуру таблицы

```
id | parent | order | name
15   0        4       какое то имя
16   0        2       какое то имя
18   16       1       какое то имя
19   18       3       какое то имя
28   15       5       какое то имя
31   16       6       какое то имя

//на выходе охота увидеть
id     | parent | order | name
16       0        2       какое то имя
  18     16       1       какое то имя
    19   18       3       какое то имя
  31     16       6       какое то имя
15       0        4       какое то имя
  28     15       5       какое то имя
```

Аналогичная структура используется в комментариях или в древовидных категориях. Что бы выстроить древовидную структуру можно перебирать базу циклом с рекурсией - минусом является большое кол-во запросов.

Есть остальные варианты? Какая то специфическая команда к mysql, или делать 1 запрос, а потом уже средствами php перебирать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю, что это целесообразно делать средствами PHP.

Предположим, что есть такие входные данные после полной выборки всех значений из базы данных (составлены на основе вашего примера):

```
// Предположим, что это корневой элемент
$arr[0]['id'] = 15;
$arr[0]['name'] = "name 1";
$arr[0]['parent'] = 0;
$arr[0]['order'] = 4;

$arr[1]['id'] = 16;
$arr[1]['name'] = "name 2";
$arr[1]['parent'] = 0;
$arr[1]['order'] = 2;

$arr[2]['id'] = 18;
$arr[2]['name'] = "name 3";
$arr[2]['parent'] = 16;
$arr[2]['order'] = 1;

$arr[3]['id'] = 19;
$arr[3]['name'] = "name 4";
$arr[3]['parent'] = 18;
$arr[3]['order'] = 3;

$arr[4]['id'] = 28;
$arr[4]['name'] = "name 5";
$arr[4]['parent'] = 15;
$arr[4]['order'] = 5;

$arr[5]['id'] = 31;
$arr[5]['name'] = "name 6";
$arr[5]['parent'] = 16;
$arr[5]['order'] = 6;
```

Напишем обработчик для вашей задачи:

```
// Функция-хелпер, сравнивающая элементы массива по ключу 'order'
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
}

// Функция, формирующая древовидный массив
function formTree($mess)
{
    if (!is_array($mess)) {
        return false;
    }

    $tree = array();

    // Формируем древовидный массив вида: 
    // id элемента => потомки этого элемента
    foreach ($mess as $value) {
        $tree[$value['parent']][] = $value;
    }

    // Сортитуем потомков по ключу 'order' в порядке возрастания
    foreach ($tree as $key => $branch) {
        usort($branch, 'sortByOrder');
        $tree[$key] = $branch;
    }

    return $tree;
}

// Функция, формирующая html-представление древовидного массива
// Элемент с ключом $parent будет считаться "корневым"

function buildTree($cats, $parent)
{
    // Если передан массив и в нем есть
    if (is_array($cats) && isset($cats[$parent])) {
        $tree = '<ul>';

        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $cat) {
            $tree .= '<li>' . $cat['id'];
            $tree .= buildTree($cats, $cat['id']);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }

        $tree .= '</ul>';
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return $tree;
}

// Сформированный и отсортированный древовидный массив
$tree = formTree($arr);

// Сформированное html-представление древовидного массива
$html_tree = buildTree($tree, 0);
```

Результат работы:

[image: html-представление массива]